# Error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

This error started to appear out of nowhere, when I log in to my app (through firebase) it has to show a list, however, when logging in, it does not show anything and this error starts to appear several times in the LOG

Log:

```
2021-04-30 11:58:33.328 7154-12129/? E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are 
not yet supported across processes.)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
    at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateAllPhoneStateLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4687)
    at 
com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.notePhoneSignalStrengthLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4717)
    at 
com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.notePhoneSignalStrength(BatteryStatsService.java:606)
    at 
com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.broadcastSignalStrengthChanged(TelephonyRegistry.java:1468)
    at 
com.android.server.TelephonyRegistry.notifySignalStrengthForPhoneId(TelephonyRegistry.java:925)
    at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub.onTransact(ITelephonyRegistry.java:157)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

I can't see what activity or fragment this error comes from, I just know that when I log in to my list afterwards, it doesn't show anything in the list and these errors appear in the LOG in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array size is smaller than the index your code try to refer to, you can add a check the index you trying to access should be smaller than the size of the array.
something like

```
if(index < yourArrayList.size()){
    value = yourArrayList[index]
   }
```

Comment: would you do this check? because my log does not point where the error comes from

Comment: where ever you have code to show the list from that data you receive from firebase, you can use that as entry point to debug your code